# Difference between eventTimeTimeout and processingTimeTimeout in mapGroupsWithState

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

What is the difference between `eventTimeTimeout` and `processingTimeTimeout` in `mapGroupsWithState`?

Also, is possible to make a state expire after every 10 min and if the data for that particular key arrives after 10 min the state should be maintained from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- processing-based timeouts rely on the time/clock of the machine your job is running. It is independent of any timestamps given in your data/events.
- event-based timeouts rely on a timestamp column within your data that serves as the event time. In that case you need to declare this timestamp as a Watermark.

More details are available in the Scala Docs on the relevant class
[GroupState](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupState.html):

With **ProcessingTimeTimeout**, the timeout duration can be set by calling GroupState.setTimeoutDuration. The timeout will occur when the clock has advanced by the set duration. Guarantees provided by this timeout with a duration of D ms are as follows:

- Timeout will never be occur before the clock time has advanced by D ms
- Timeout will occur eventually when there is a trigger in the query (i.e. after D ms). So there is a no strict upper bound on when the timeout would occur. For example, the trigger interval of the query will affect when the timeout actually occurs. If there is no data in the stream (for any group) for a while, then their will not be any trigger and timeout function call will not occur until there is data.
- Since the processing time timeout is based on the clock time, it is affected by the variations in the system clock (i.e. time zone changes, clock skew, etc.).

With **EventTimeTimeout**, the user also has to specify the event time watermark in the query using Dataset.withWatermark(). With this setting, data that is older than the watermark are filtered out. The timeout can be set for a group by setting a timeout timestamp usingGroupState.setTimeoutTimestamp(), and the timeout would occur when the watermark advances beyond the set timestamp. You can control the timeout delay by two parameters - (i) watermark delay and an additional duration beyond the timestamp in the event (which is guaranteed to be newer than watermark due to the filtering). Guarantees provided by this timeout are as follows:

- Timeout will never be occur before watermark has exceeded the set timeout.
- Similar to processing time timeouts, there is a no strict upper bound on the delay when the timeout actually occurs. The watermark can advance only when there is data in the stream, and the event time of the data has actually advanced.

---

> "Also, is possible to make a state expire after every 10 min and if the data for that particular key arrives after 10 min the state should be maintained from the beginning?"

This is happening automatically when using `mapGroupsWithState`. You just need to make sure to actually remove the state after the 10 minutes.